# how can i make a excel sheet out of a dynamic html table with input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I am using this javascript function to generate an excel sheet out of a html table since some fields in the table are enclosed in input tag rather then td i am not getting those in my excel sheet.

```js
function exportDataToExcel(table_id, filename = '')
       {
          var downloadurl;
          var fileType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
          var tableSelect = document.getElementById(table_id);
          var dataHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
          filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'user_details.xls';
          downloadurl = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(downloadurl);
         if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
           {
              var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', dataHTML],
               {
                  type:  fileType
              });
             navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
           }
        else
          {
           downloadurl.href = 'data:' + fileType + ', ' + dataHTML;
           downloadurl.download = filename;
          downloadurl.click();
       }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What file-type is meant by "excel sheet" (xlsx, xls etc)? If that doesnt matter: 1. create a CSV (seperate with tabs) in javascript - which should be easiest. 2a. save the CSV as file or 2b. let user copy the CSV into clipboard (ctrl-c) 3a. let Excel open the CSV as Excel sheet 3b. let user paste CSV (tap seperated) into existing Excel sheet (ctrl-v)

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you should to find library for excel-sheets creating...

Comment: I think you should give a proper example of code or a concrete library that can do so.